# Omit objects with no filled properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

consider javascript object like this:

```
const fooObject = {
   firstName: 'John',
   lastName: null,
   age: 43,
   address: {
      city: null,
      country: null
   }
}
```

I am usually using function `omitBy` to remove not set fields like this `omitBy(fooObject, isNil)` but it doesn't work for objects like mentioned `fooObject`. There is some nice way how to remove nested empty objects and fields on given object with lodash or vanilla js?

My expected result for `fooObject` object is this:

```
{
   firstName: 'John',
   age: 43
}
```

If the address will contain at least one filled field city, then the result should be:

```
{
   firstName: 'John',
   age: 43,
   address: {
      city: 'Los Angeles',
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a recursive function, that removes all `null` values, and if it have a value, which is an object or array, it needs to clean it, and so on. If a cleaned object/array is empty, we can skip it.

With lodash you can use `_.transform()`, which handles both arrays and objects.

```js
const deepClean = obj => _.transform(obj, (acc, value, key) => {
  if(_.isNull(value)) return; // ignore null values

  if (_.isObject(value)) { // handle objects / arrays
    const cleanObj = deepClean(value) // clean the object

    if(!_.isEmpty(cleanObj)) acc[key] = cleanObj  // if it's not empty assign it to current key
  } else { // handle primitives
    acc[key] = value // assign value to current key
  }
})

console.log(deepClean(fooObject = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: null,
  age: 43,
  address: {
    city: null,
    country: null
  }
}))

console.log(deepClean(fooObject = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: null,
  age: 43,
  address: {
    city: null,
    country: 'Spain',
  }
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create recursive function with `reduce` method that will traverse object on multiple levels and create new object without any null values.

```js
const a = {"firstName":"John","lastName":null,"age":43,"address":{"city":null,"country":null}}
const b = {"firstName":"John","lastName":null,"age":43,"address":{"city":null,"country":null, random: { foo: null, baz: 1}}}

function removeNulls(data) {
  return Object.entries(data)
    .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
      if (v !== null) {
        if (typeof v === 'object') {
          const child = removeNulls(v);
          if (Object.keys(child).length) {
            r[k] = child
          }
        } else {
          r[k] = v;
        }
      }

      return r;
    }, {})
}

console.log(removeNulls(a))
console.log(removeNulls(b))
```